# Azure Tagging Policy - Create Required Tag of TTO with a Date Formatted in YYY-MM-DD

Tags: azure, tags

how can i create an Azure tag policy that would enforce a date on a tag name of TTO? I am looking for the date to be in a specific format of YYY-MM-DD. i found a snippet of code posted somewhere else here, but not understand where it would go in policy against a TTO tag name:

```
{
  "if": {
    "not": {
      "field": "tags[date]",
      "match": "####-##-##"
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```

Thanks

I tried adding this snippet of code into a custom code i found somewhere with variables and into require but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for the date to be in a specific format of YYY-MM-DD.

The policy will deny the resources creation on subscription level that have a **TTO** tag value that does not match the pattern `"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$",` which represents a date in the format **YYYY-MM-DD**. it will only allow resources with **TTO** tag values that are valid dates in the specified format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

I have followed this [MS DOCUMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure) as a reference to create Azure Policy. Here is the updated policy:

> ```json
>     {
>       "mode": "All",
>       "policyRule": {
>         "if": {
>           "not": {
>             "anyOf": [
>               {
>                 "field": "tags['TTO']",
>                 "match": "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         "then": {
>           "effect": "deny"
>         }
>       },
>       "parameters": {}
>     }
> ```

When I try to create a resource with a tag named **TTO** and a value of **venkat**, the policy is denying the resource creation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! i tried this out but i still cannot get it to work for some reason??
I made an edit to the policy so that it would only target resource groups. I get the message indicating i need a TTO tag, but the value is still not being enforced? i tried this in 2 of my tenants, one which has no policies to make sure i'm not colliding with something else. 

"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
},
{
"field": "tags['TTO']",
"match": "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"
}
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
 }
 }

Comment: i tried this out, and added a portion to target resource group creations. true it is not allowing random text in the tag value, but it is also not allowing any dates. it has to match exactly ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ . It's not excepting this as a variable to enter in a date and is being takin literally. anyt houghts around that?